# Memory efficient way to keep paired lines (string match)

Tags: python, linux, bash, iteration

I have very large text files that I need to sort through and remove all unpaired lines. Paired lines are consecutive lines that have the same 32 characters at the beginning of each line. I currently have a script written in python with a while loop that iterates through the lines, compares the first 32 characters of lines i and (i+1), then only outputs lines in pairs. However, this method is very memory intensive and slow since each file can be several gigabytes. Is there a faster and more efficient method that you recommend? For reference, I am working on a SLURM Linux server.

Comment: How is this memory intensive? You never need to store more than two lines using your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses my two favorite Python modules, `itertools` and `collections`. Use `itertools.groupby` to walk the lines in the file, grouping together those with a common prefix. Use `next()` to pull only the first element from the `lines` iterator, and then a 0-length `deque` to consume the remainder of the `lines` iterator.

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import deque
consume = deque(maxlen=0).extend
from operator import itemgetter

prefix_slice = slice(0,32)
with open('bigfile.txt') as infile):
    for _,lines in groupby(infile, key=itemgetter(prefix_slice)):
        print next(lines).rstrip('\n')
        # have to consume iterator over remaining lines before
        # advancing to next groupby key
        consume(lines)
```

This will hold only a single line in memory at a time, plus the 32-character prefix for comparison with following lines. (Will collapse all consecutive lines that share a common 32-character prefix, not just pairs.)

Comment: With itertools, how can I use this method to iterate through keys to find keys with 2 elements? Is it possible to use this method to have a for loop through key and items?

Comment: In `for _,lines in groupby(etc.`, the `lines` return value is an iterator over *all* the matching elements. In your post, you implied that only the first value was significant, so that is why I wrote this answer the way I did. If you want to get *all* the elements and work with them, the simplest is to just save them to a list and work with the list like you would in any other Python code. Replace the body of the for loop with: `lines = list(lines)`  . Now, instead of an iterator, you have a list, which you can do the `len()` of to see how many elements there are, and access any/all of them.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using itertools decreased computing time over 10 fold.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be memory intensive as long as you don't read in the whole file at once, but iterate over it. Something like this should do:

```
last = ""
with open("mybibgfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f: 
        if last[:32] == line[:32]
            last = line
            continue
        print(line)
        last = line
```